# Why are the icons from my storyboard not displayed anymore?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a slide menu with some rows and each row has an icon which I set up in the storyboard.

[image]

My icons are not displayed anymore in the app. I tried to add some closures and set up the images with a specific image, height, and width and return them in my `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method. But the icons are not displayed correctly.
How can modify the code shown below so that my icons are displayed properly?

```
enum MenuType: Int, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {   
case plan, documentation, visitlist, document, constructdiary, plancorrection
case sync, settings, info
  var section: Int {
    switch self {
    case .plan, .documentation, .visitlist, .document, . constructdiary, .plancorrection: return 0
    case .sync, .settings, .info: return 1
    }
}

var row: Int? {
    switch self.section {
    case 0: return self.rawValue
    case 1: return self.rawValue - MenuType.allCases.filter{ $0.section < self.section }.count
    default: return nil
    }
}

var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .plan:
        return "Pläne"
    case .documentation:
        return "Dokumentationen"
    case .visitlist:
        return "Begehungen"
    case .document:
        return "Dokument"
    case .constructdiary:
        return "Bautagesberichte"
    case .plancorrection:
        return "Plankorrekturen"
    case .sync:
        return "Synchronisation"
    case .settings:
        return "Einstellungen"
    case .info:
        return "Info"
    }
} }

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var didTapMenuType: ((MenuType) -> Void)?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupImageView()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return Array(Set(MenuType.allCases.map{ $0.section })).count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return MenuType.allCases.filter{ $0.section == section }.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let type = MenuType.allCases.first(where: { $0.section == indexPath.section && $0.row == indexPath.row })
    cell.textLabel?.text = type?.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let menuType = MenuType.allCases.first(where: { $0.section == indexPath.section && $0.row == indexPath.row }) else {return}
    dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
        self?.didTapMenuType?(menuType)
    }
}

private func setupImageView() {
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
}}
```

Icons should be displayed as shown in the picture above.

Comment: Do you have image property in `enum MenuType`?

Comment: No, I did set it up in my storyboard only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard select table view of the `MenuViewController` and change its type to Static Cells

[image]

Then delete `numberOfSections`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAt indexPath` methods from the code. Keep `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method only in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAt` method you are creating new cell every-time, instead of reuse cell. See this line of code:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

You should change above line of code with this one:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

I hope this will fix your issue.